# MySQL: UPDATE Concurrency

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-5.5

I have a table with two columns: item_id (int, auto inc) and item_counter (int, default value 0)

A user on a web page is allotted a few items by entering a form. This runs:

```
SELECT * FROM itemtable WHERE item_counter<100 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5
```

This is followed by an UPDATE query increasing the item_counter of each of those items.

```
UPDATE itemtable SET item_counter=item_counter + 1 WHERE item_id=:item_id
```

About 20-50 users will be doing this operation at once.

A simple application. 1 SELECT and 5 UPDATE operations are sequential for each user, and I want the item_counter to be accurate (avoiding this scenario: an item_id is selected as having item_counter 99 but gets updated by some other user before this user is able to update it.

Should I use concurrency/locking in this? 
I don't know if InnoDB's row-level locking is inherent to all UPDATE operations or any syntax changes are required?. I'm wondering what should I use here.. or don't use anything at all.

Comment: Yup. Thanks. Though I'm wondering if transactions are the right way to go in this situation, i.e. I hope they're not overkill?

Comment: Why you use 2 Query. you can do it with one; UPDATE itemtable SET item_counter=item_counter + 1 WHERE item_counter<100 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5

Comment: OR with 2 Querys with "FOR UPDATE". That will lock the record

SELECT * FROM itemtable FOR UPDATE WHERE item_counter<100 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5;  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-locking-reads.html

Comment: Yup. Worked. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
BEGIN;
SELECT ... FOR UPDATE;  -- "FOR UPDATE" is the secret sauce.
UPDATE ...
COMMIT;
```